# curl: using multipart with post params

Tags: c++, http, curl

If I do

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post_params);
```

the server will do not see multipart, but if I coment the second line

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);
//curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post_params);
```

it'll do.

What's wrong here?

**UPD:** So, now the question is, whether it's possible to put value to a param, so that that value was in POST parameters array on server-side? I'm trying

```
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Disposition: form-data");

    //action=upload
    curl_formadd(&formpost,
        &lastptr,
        CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "action",
        CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "upload",
        CURLFORM_CONTENTHEADER, headers,
        CURLFORM_CONTENTTYPE, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
        CURLFORM_END);
```

But that's not working!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does `post_params` contain?

Comment: `post_params="action=upload&clientID=" + clientId`

Comment: Well, that's not a multipart message, it's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Your string has to be a valid multipart message, and you have to set the correct `Content-Type:` header (probably `multipart/form-data`)... I suggest you [read this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages) for info on how multipart messages work.

Comment: @DaveRandom, that means that I have to encode `post_params` in some way?

Comment: It means you have to *create* `post_params` in a *different* way. The string would look completely different. Have a read of the Wikipedia article I linked to before, it has an example of how a multipart message will look, and links to everything you need to read about how the standard works.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I still can't catch how to pass `post_params` in this different way.

Comment: It's not about how you pass it, it's about how you make the string in the first place. You will need, at a minimum, one more variable `boundary`, which holds a random boundary string to separate the message parts. Then you need to make a string which is like `post_params = "--"+boundary+"\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"action\"\r\n\r\nupload\r\n--"+boundary+"\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"clientID\"\r\n\r\n"+clientId+"\r\n--"+boundary+"--"` - in the format depicted in the standard for multipart messages

Answer (score 2):

I ended up mostly following the example code here: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multi-post.html

Here's a sample of the code that ended up working for me based on the curl example link:

```
... 
CURL *curl;
curl_mime *form;

curl = curl_easy_init();

/*  Set the headers for the request. */
scoped_curl_slist headers;
headers.list = NULL;
string session_header = "Authorization: Bearer " + token;
headers.list = curl_slist_append(headers.list, session_header.c_str());
headers.list = curl_slist_append(headers.list, "cache-control: no-cache");
headers.list = curl_slist_append(headers.list, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers.list);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "your_url.com");

/* Create the form */
form = curl_mime_init(curl);

/* Fill in the file upload field */
curl_mimepart *field = curl_mime_addpart(form);
curl_mime_name(field, "upload");
curl_mime_filedata(field, "C:/file_name.txt");

/* Fill in the filename field */
field = curl_mime_addpart(form);
curl_mime_name(field, "name");
curl_mime_data(field, "file_name.txt", CURL_ZERO_TERMINATED);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MIMEPOST, form);

CURLcode result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
...
curl_mime_free(form);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
curl_slist_free_all(headers);
```

Comment: I tried this... the form was sending without the boundary and causing a bad request